# Is there any static checking tool to check buggy code like this

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I wrote the some buggy code like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    string some_file = "afdfadf";

    if(true)
    {
        string some_file = "/"+ some_file;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will throw an exception when calling std::operator+.

I guess this is because in the if statement the second some_file is an uninitialized string.

Is there any static checking tool that can help find this kind of bug?

Comment: Lint is the keyword sought: [cpplint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpplint/) and then experiment with warning levels of the compiler (as in for instance java this would be a compile time error).

Comment: @JoopEggen, can cpplint find this problem?

Comment: Should as it does data flow analysis. Maybe not the bad style of reusing the same variable name. I had another lint, some years back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has a warning for that case:

```
$ g++ t.cc -Wshadow
t.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
t.cc:11:16: warning: declaration of ‘some_file’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
t.cc:7:12: warning: shadowed declaration is here [-Wshadow]
```

Comment: But this warning doesn't point to the use of an uninitialized variable. Shadowing a previous local variable is per so not a bug.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki, no, but it's the bug the question is about. If it was just about self-initialization the first `some_file` variable wouldn't be in the example, would it?

Comment: The first ´some_file´ makes the bug just harder to spot.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki: No, it doesnt't, at least not when it is of std::string type, if there were no shadowing, there were also no bug, since the variable used for concatenation would be initialized.

Comment: @PlasmaHH if there where no first `some_file`, the initialization of the second `some_file` would still use the second, uninitialized `some_file`. This version of main() has the same problem: `int main() { std::string s = "seas" + s; }`

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Torsten's last comment is right, the object's constructor will be called with the result of `"seas" + s` which depends on `s` which hasn't been constructed yet. Undefined behaviour. I still think `-Wshadow` solves this particular problem though.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: My point is that this particular incarnation of the bug stems from the confusion about the variable name; had the outer variable been another name (i.e. no shadowing taking place) I am rather sure that whoever wrote the code had used the outer name after the `+`. Of course the code is UB, but I think the core of the mistakes programmers make at that point lies in the shadowing.

Comment: Ah, right, gotcha. _"I think the core of the mistakes programmers make at that point lies in the shadowing"_ I certainly agree with that part, that's why my answer suggested `-Wshadow` not `-Winit-self` (and also because GCC's `-Winit-self` fails to diagnost this! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I just tried, clang can help find the bug:

```
[~]$ clang bug.cpp 
bug.cpp:11:29: warning: variable 'some_file' is uninitialized when used within
      its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
    string some_file = "/"+ some_file;
           ~~~~~~~~~        ^~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

Compilers can warn you about using a variable in its own initialization.

In GCC and CLANG, you can use `-Winit-self`
I am not sure about MSVC, but compiling with /W4 might give you a warning about those, too.

Comment: `-Wshadow` is also useful in this case.

Comment: I'm surprised that the compilers operating in default mode don't detect this;  it is use of an uninitialized variable.  You don't need to detect shadowing [or "self-init"] (what, I would have known in advance of finding this bug that I needed to add this to my command line?) for this error to get caught.

Comment: GCC does not catch this with `-Winit-self`, because the type is a non-trivial class type with a constructor, and the compiler isn't smart enough to track the uninitialized data through the constructor invocation.  Clang does diagnose it.

Comment: A problem is that my project is big, and -Wshadow also report warning on the following case which is common in my project:                     struct S{ S(a):a(a); public int a;}

Answer (score 0):

I was quit happy with using pclint. It will find this type of errors but it might take some time to configure it when used with an existing, larger code base.

Comment: Try PVS-Studio. Configure is almost not required.